# How to get rid of warning "Creating EvaluationContext with no beanFactory"?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm trying to setup a dynamic `IntegrationFlow` to read files from a local directory. Therefore I've created the following parameterizable class:

```java
@Configuration
public class FileConsoleFlow {

    @Bean("flowBuilderFactory")
    Function<Properties, IntegrationFlow> flowBuilderFactory() {
        return (properties) -> new SimpleFlowBuilder(properties).build();
    }

    static class SimpleFlowBuilder {

        private Properties properties;

        public FlowBuilder(Properties properties) {
            this.properties = properties;
        }

        public IntegrationFlow build() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(localSource(), c -> c.poller(pollerMetadata()))
                    .handle(message -> System.out.println(message))
                    .get();
        }

        public FileReadingMessageSource localSource() {
            CompositeFileListFilter<File> filters = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
            filters.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(properties.getProperty("local-file-pattern")));
            filters.addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>(10000));

            RecursiveDirectoryScanner scanner = new RecursiveDirectoryScanner();
            scanner.setFilter(filters);

            FileReadingMessageSource fileSource = new FileReadingMessageSource();
            fileSource.setDirectory(new File(properties.getProperty("local-directory")));
            fileSource.setScanner(scanner);
            return fileSource;
        }

        public PollerMetadata pollerMetadata() {
            return Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)
                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(100)
                    .advice(transactionInterceptor())
                    .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())
                    .get();
        }

        public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor() {
            return new TransactionInterceptorBuilder()
                    .transactionManager(txManager())
                    .build();
        }

        public TransactionManager txManager() {
            return new PseudoTransactionManager();
        }

        public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
            ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor processor =
                    new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();

            SpelExpressionParser spelParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
            processor.setAfterCommitExpression(spelParser.parseExpression("payload.delete()"));
            processor.setAfterRollbackExpression(spelParser.parseExpression("payload.renameTo(new java.io.File(payload.absolutePath + '.FAILED'))"));

            return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(processor);
        }
    }
}
```

The parameterized flows are registered with the help of the `IntegrationFlowContext` as follows:

```java
...
integrationFlowContext.registration(flow)
    .autoStartup(false)
    .id("flow-" + id)
    .register();
...
integrationFlowContext.getRegistry().forEach((name, flow) -> flow.start());
```

After starting up the application I get the following warning:

```sh
 2022-02-08 14:11:41.951  WARN [,1e3c4776ef54251e,1e3c4776ef54251e] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.expression.ExpressionUtils         : Creating EvaluationContext with no beanFactory
java.lang.RuntimeException: No beanFactory
at org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils.createStandardEvaluationContext(ExpressionUtils.java:90) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.transaction.ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.createEvaluationContext(ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.java:218) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.transaction.ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.prepareEvaluationContextToUse(ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.java:202) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.transaction.ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.doProcess(ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.java:141) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.transaction.ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.processAfterCommit(ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.java:125) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.transaction.DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory$DefaultTransactionalResourceSynchronization.processResourceAfterCommit(DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory.java:79) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.transaction.DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory$DefaultTransactionalResourceSynchronization.processResourceAfterCommit(DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory.java:53) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSynchronization.afterCommit(ResourceHolderSynchronization.java:87) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:135) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:936) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:782) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy101.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:413) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

If I understood things correctly, the `IntegrationFlowContext` is responsible for the creation of the integration-beans (and thus the setting of the beanFactory). But then why do I get this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` must be declared as a bean and therefore its `BeanFactory` requirements would be fulfilled.

Please, revise all your volatile objects and consider to make some of them as global singleton beans.

I believe all of these could go to the main configuration, not dynamic: `PollerMetadata`, `TransactionInterceptor`, `TransactionManager` and `TransactionSynchronizationFactory`. The dynamic part in your solution is really just that `FileReadingMessageSource`.

It is better to use as less dynamic as possible for better performance and proper reusability. You also would avoid duplications whenever they are not needed.

I would even move that `.handle(message -> System.out.println(message))` to the separate global singleton `IntegrationFlow` and use only a channel reference from this one to avoid extra duplication.